# rqt_plot not found

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the ROS tutorial, when I'm trying to plot the position of the turtle, I get the following error:

```
$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot --args /turtle1/pose/x:y
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rqt_plot below /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rqt/rqt_plot
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files, 
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rqt/rqt_plot
[rosrun]   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rqt/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?
By the way, `rqt_gui` works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50296/rqt_plot-not-found/) by [3lectrologos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3774/3lectrologos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rqt_plot is a plugin for the gui.  If you run rqt_gui, there should be a 'Plugins' menu item in the main window that lets you select a plugin to display. You can then specify the topic in the text box in the panel that comes up.

EDIT: To get more plugins for rqt, just apt-get them, as in the guide [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/UserGuide/Install/Groovy).

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2013-05-18**:
In the 'Plugins' menu item in the main window,there is only one plugin:ROS GRAPH.How can I add other plugins?